# Make sure ajax function finishes before 2nd non-ajax function fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Similar to the question I just asked,

If I call an ajax function in jQuery and then a non ajax function how can I prevent the non-ajax function from firing until after the first ajax callback function has completed.  Will declaring async: false in the first ajax function be enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about this:

```
$.ajax({...});
someFunction();
```

where `someFunction()` won't occur until the AJAX call completes then you have three options:

1. Make the AJAX call `async: false`. *Don't do this*. It'll make your page unresponsive;
2. Put `someFunction()` in the complete/success/error callbacks of the AJAX call. This is the recommended approach; or
3. Use aplugin to manage a request queue eg [Ajax Queue](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue).

The first A in AJAX stands for "asynchronous". You just need to get used to the fact that these calls are asynchronous and stop trying to force a synchronous programming model on top of them. Adapt to the new programming model.

Comment: what's so bad about `async: false`?
I used it before and it seems ok

Comment: Because while the request is happening the page (and the whole browser if you're not using Chrome) will lock up. If this is 100ms or less it probably won't be noticeable but if the request gets delayed, there are network issues or the server process is reasonably long-running this is going to be a huge problem.

Comment: It seems like chaining callback functions also causes the browser to lock up.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery AJAX functions let you provide a callback that is only called after the request is finished. Call your non-ajax function as part of that callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback functions like this:

```
$("#btnSample").on("click", function (e) {

 $.ajax({
    url: 'some_url',
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { 
      "p1": v1, 
      "p2": v2
    },
    success: function(result) {
      //call you second function here!
    }  
  }
});

});
```